# Anible playbook with json loop does not work if json key has a dash in the name

Tags: ansible

Ansible playbook does not work if json key has a dash in the name, without the dash it works fine.

I tried with from_json and json_query, but I'm getting the same issue

The is the output I have to parse:

```
ok: [2.2.2.2] => {
    "bgp": {
        "response": {
            "@status": "success",
            "result": {
                "entry": [
                    {
                        "@peer": "V4",
                        "@vr": "VR",
                        "ORF-entry-received": "0",
                        "aggregate-confed-as": "yes",
                        "config": {
                            "remove-private-as": "yes"
                        },
                        "connect-retry-interval": "15",
                        "established-counts": "0",
                        "holdtime": "0",
                        "holdtime-config": "90",
                        "idle-hold": "15",
                        "keepalive": "0",
                        "keepalive-config": "30",
                        "last-error": null,
                        "last-update-age": "634",
                        "local-address": "3.3.3.3",
                        "msg-total-in": "0",
                        "msg-total-out": "0",
                        "msg-update-in": "0",
                        "msg-update-out": "0",
                        "multi-hop-ttl": "1",
                        "nexthop-peer": "no",
                        "nexthop-self": "no",
                        "nexthop-thirdparty": "yes",
                        "open-delay": "0",
                        "passive": "no",
                        "password-set": "no",
                        "peer-address": "2.2.2.2",
                        "peer-capability": null,
                        "peer-group": "PEER_A",
                        "peer-router-id": "0.0.0.0",
                        "peering-type": "Unspecified",
                        "prefix-counter": null,
                        "prefix-limit": "5000",
                        "reflector-client": "not-client",
                        "remote-as": "65000",
                        "same-confederation": "no",
                        "status": "Connect",
                        "status-duration": "0",
                        "status-flap-counts": "49"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is my current code (the problem happens when I add the "peer-address"):

```
 - debug:
     msg:
       peer-address: "{{ item.peer-address }}"
       status: "{{ item.status }}"
   loop: "{{ (result_3.stdout|from_json).response.result.entry }}"
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'peer'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/Playbook-v2.yml': line 49, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n   - debug:\n     ^ here\n"}

I want to get just the two keys and values that I'm parsing:

```
"peer-address": "2.2.2.2"
"status": "Connect"
```

Comment: Hey could I suggest changing the title to your question to: "Loop over json not working when key contains dash", I think it'd be a bit less cluttered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your problem here:

```
peer-address: "{{ item.peer-address }}"
```

The name `peer-address` isn't a valid identifier (in Jinja syntax, like in most languages, variable names cannot include `-`).  You can instead use the alternate syntax for referencing keys:

```
peer-address: "{{ item['peer-address'] }}"
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was doing something very wrong